# Unable to call a function with ENTER key

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, ajax

I need to pass in some values to my function
I want the function to run when I press ENTER KEY in PHP

the function is update()
This is my PHP

```
    echo '<input type="text" size="23" id= n'.$row["ContactID"].'
class = "name" placeholder="Contact Name" 
value="'.$row["Name"].' 
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) updatename(this,'.$row["ContactID"].')  ">';
```

my javascript

```
function updatename(item, cid)
{
            var varname =  $(item).val();   
            var originaltext =  $(item).val();  
            $.ajax({
                url: 'changeContact.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{
                varname: varname
                },
                success:function (data) {

                    if (data == '1')
                    {
                        $("#status")
                        .addClass("success")
                        .html("Data saved successfully")
                        .fadeIn('fast')
                        .delay(3000)
                        .fadeOut('slow');   

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#status")
                        .addClass("error")
                        .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                        .fadeIn('fast')
                        .delay(3000)
                        .fadeOut('slow');   
                    }
                }
            });   


         }
```

Why does it don't seem to be working? Nothing have been send to my database, even I change to a simple alert, nothing appear
How can I improve it?

Comment: any error in console??? Make sure, that function is calling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your HTML is invalid.

```
...
value="'.$row["Name"].'                 <--------- " is missing
onkeydown="if (eve...
```

Comment: onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) updatename(this,'.$row["ContactID"].') ">'; is it correct?

Comment: `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` - doesn't matter. You haven't closed `value` attribute - that's the problem. Add a double quote, as I showed.

Comment: In general, HTML standard recommends to quote out all attributes, including `id`. It will make your code more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="your id" onkeypress="MAGIC(event);" />

function MAGIC(event){
  $("#id").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            //your code to be executed
        }
   }
```

Comment: I cannt get my Id of my DIV, because the DIv is generated by my SQL query, so id is auto increment

Comment: @Ryan:apparently,the methodology that you are using is super complicated and i dont understand the need of auto-incremented ids.Some explanation??